# Running a process inside a worker thread (C#)

Tags: c#, shell, cmd

I am trying to run several external application from inside my application. Assume that I want to run an application called LongtimeRun.exe for 10 times and each time that this applications runs, it takes around 30s to finish ( total time is 300 sec or 5 minutes!). I also want to give user some progress indication ( for example how many times the application runs).

I can create a batch file and run LongTimeRun.exe there 10 times, but then I am not able to show any progress report.

I have this code which works:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

public class CommandProcessor
{
        private readonly string binDirectory;
    private readonly string workingDirectory;
    public CommandProcessor(string workingDirectory, string binFolderName)
    {
        binDirectory = Path.Combine(FileSystem.ApplicationDirectory, binFolderName);
        this.workingDirectory = workingDirectory;
    }
    public int RunCommand(string command, string argbase, params string[] args)
    {
        var commandPath = Path.Combine(binDirectory, command);
        var formattedArgumets = string.Format(argbase, args);

        var myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = commandPath;
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = formattedArgumets;
        myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = this.workingDirectory;
        myProcess.Start();
        myProcess.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

When I calling it in tis way:

```
private void RunCommands()
{
  var command = "LongRunCommand.exe";
  string binDirectory = Path.Combine(FileSystem.ApplicationDirectory, binFolderName);
  var cp = new CommandProcessor(this.workingDirectory, binDirectory);
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
       cp.RunCommand(Command, "-i {0}", i);
  }
 }
```

The above code is called as part of direct call and blocks the application (the applications seems to hangs during this process.

To solve the hanging problem, I used a backgroundworker as follow:

```
   var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
   worker.DoWork += this.WorkerDoWork;
   worker.RunWorkerCompleted += this.workerRunWorkerCompleted;
   worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

and called runcommand inside WorkerDoWork.

Now the application exited after it called this line:

```
 myProcess.WaitForExit();
```

There is no debug info and exit code is -1.

What is the problem and how can  solve it?

Is there any better way to achieve my goal without using BackgroundWorker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is because your `BackgroundWorker` threads are still running but you application completes its life-cycle and ends (it is not being blocked by them so its path is clear to end) therefore killing these threads.

You need to inform the application **NOT** to exit while the background threads are still running. You could have a counter that is incremented when each thread starts and then as they complete they can decrement the counter.

Inside your main application thread you could wait until the counter reaches zero before ending the application.

Obviously you will need to take into account locking (i.e. two threads try to decrement counter at the same time) but this should give you a starter.